# What is the best way to install tensorflow and mongodb in docker?

Tags: mongodb, docker, tensorflow

I want to create a docker container or image and have tensorflow and mongodb installed, I have seen that there are docker images for each application, but I need them to be working together, from a mongodb database I must extract the data to feed a model created in tensorflow.

Then I want to know if it is possible to have a configuration like that, since I have tried with a ubuntu container and inside it to install the applications I need, but I don't know if there is another way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that I find this post, and just found one solution for myself. Maybe not the one for you, BTW.

What I did is: docker pull mongo and run as daemon:

```
#!/bin/bash
export VOLUME='/home/user/code'
docker run -itd \
    --name mongodb \
    --publish 27017:27017 \
    --volume ${VOLUME}:/code \
    mongo
```

Here

- the 'd' in '-itd' means running as daemon (like service, not
  interactive).
- The --volume may not be used.

Then docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow and run it with:

```
#!/bin/bash
export VOLUME='/home/user/code'
docker run \
    -u 1000:1000 \
    -it --rm \
    --name tensorflow \
    --volume ${VOLUME}:/code \
    -w /code \
    -e HOME=/code/tf_mongodb \
    tensorflow/tensorflow bash
```

Here

- the -u make docker bash with same ownership as host machine;
- the --volume make host folder /home/user/code mapping to /code in docker;
- the -w work make docker bash start from /code, which is /home/user/code in host;
- the -e HOME= option sign bash $HOME folder such that later you can pip install.

Now you have bash prompt such that you can

- create virtual env folder under /code (which is mapping to /home/user/code),
- activate venv,
- pip install pymongo,
- then you can connect to mongodb you run in docker (localhost may not work, please use host IP address).